# How to compare two strings in this way?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm working with JavaScript, and I have two strings like this :

```
var week1="1.345.7", // each digit refers to one day of the week
    week2="123..6.";
```

Now I want to return a value from 1 to 7 which refers to the number of days in common.

In the previous example I should return 2, because we have both weeks have Monday and Wednesday (1 and 3).

How can I achieve the above ?

Comment: I would use some code, probably javascript as that is the language you have tagged

Comment: I don't know how to proceed .. :s

Comment: Split it to smaller manageable steps: 1. Split a string into an array of days set 2. Find what numbers are common in both arrays. Every time you stuck - decompose a task into smaller ones you can manage with and solve them one after another.

Comment: hint: Array has a filter method and a length property

Comment: hint: Arrays (and strings) can be looped over

Comment: What would happen if two `.` are in common?

Comment: For example we have two companies, each compagnie offer a service in weeks, when we have `.` it means that it does not offer the service in this day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to throw another option out there, if you split a string with an empty string argument, you get an array of one-character strings. This makes them easy to iterate, but also if you're targeting browsers that support ECMAscript 5.1 (most notably IE 9+) you can use the **reduce** function. It's generally a good fit when you're passing in an array that you want to iterate and return a single value. This could be more concise, but I think it's easier to follow this way.

```js
var week1="1.345.7";
var week2="123..6.";

function weekDaysInCommon(w1, w2) {
  //split to convert w1 to an array.
  //"1.345.7" becomes ["1", ".", "3", "4", "5", ".", "7"]
  w1 = w1.split('');
  //countCharactersAtSameIndex(w2) returns the function to use as the callback, with w2 accessible to it via closure
  //the second arg, 0, is the initial value.
  return w1.reduce(countCharactersAtSameIndex(w2), 0);
}

function countCharactersAtSameIndex(comparisonWeek) {
  comparisonWeek = comparisonWeek.split('');
  return function(total, day, index) {
    if(comparisonWeek[index] === day) {
      return total + 1;
    } else {
      return total;
    }
  }
}

document.write(weekDaysInCommon(week1, week2) + ' days in common');
```

Further reading:
MDN has a good doc on the reduce function - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 4):

Each character is either `.` or its index, so you can represent it with a bit.

```
"0b" + "1.345.7".replace(/./g, c=>c==='.'?0:1); // "0b1011101"
"0b" + "123..6.".replace(/./g, c=>c==='.'?0:1); // "0b1110010"
```

Then, you can use the bitwise operator AND `&`:

```
  "0b1011101"
& "0b1110010";
// 0b1010000
```

Finally, you only need to convert it back to string and count the number of `1`:

```
0b1010000.toString(2).split('1').length-1; // 2
```

Probably I wouldn't do it like this, but just for fun :)

---

In fact, to waste less memory, you could store the data as numbers instead of strings

```
0b1011101; //  93 - only needs 64 bits!
0b1110010; // 114 - only needs 64 bits!
```

And to retrieve the data

```
0b1011101 >> 6 & 1; // 1 - 1st bit
0b1011101 >> 5 & 1; // 0 - 2nd bit
0b1011101 >> 4 & 1; // 1 - 3rd bit
0b1011101 >> 3 & 1; // 1 - 4th bit
0b1011101 >> 2 & 1; // 1 - 5th bit
0b1011101 >> 1 & 1; // 0 - 6th bit
0b1011101 >> 0 & 1; // 1 - 7th bit
```

Comment: The downvoter probably believes there exist a commonly used calendar system with more than 64 days in a week :D

Comment: @zerkms: Actually 52 bits.

Comment: @slebetman 32: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-binary-bitwise-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Comment: Warning: if someone is gonna use this for weeks with 32 days, they should use `>>>` instead of `>>` to treat the number as unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Get a list of digits from the first string using a quick regexp, then filter it to keep only the ones that are in the other one, then see how many there are with `length`.

```
(week1.match(/\d/g) || []) . filter(n => week2.includes(n)) . length
```

In a "code golf" spirit, you could write this as a generator, taking advantage of the ability of `for...of` to loop across characters in a string:

```
function *common(a, b) {
  for (c of a) if (c !== '.' && b.includes(c)) yield c;
}

console.log(...common(a, b))
```